# Does switching between Bond and Equity closely tracking Interest rate generate more returns?

Tags: fixed-income, equities, quant-trading-strategies

Is there an evidence to suggest that we buy bond during high interest regime and when interest rates goes down , we sell the bond and buy Equity Index .. Repeat this by closely following the central bank's policy ? Is there a flaw in this approach ?